# Get UsedRange with Late Binding

Tags: c#, excel, late-binding

i am trying to use Late Binding to my App work in any PC with any version of the Excel.

So i was reading and trying to implement the examples i saw, but this is so confusing.

I create the instance successfully and open file succesfully, but how i get the UsedRange?

My code:

```
object excelApp;
object book;
object usedrange;

excelType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application");
excelApp = Activator.CreateInstance(excelType);


object docs = excelApp.GetType().InvokeMember("Workbooks",
    BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, excelApp, null);


object[] parms = { "C:\\ABC", Missing.Value, true };
book = docs.GetType().InvokeMember("Open",
    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, docs, parms);


object[] params2 = { "UsedRange", Missing.Value };
usedrange = book.GetType().InvokeMember("Range",
    BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, book, params2);
```

And then how i can get a row and then Cell by Cell?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: WorkBook has neither a Range nor a UsedRange member.  Make this work early-bound first.  Leverage the C# version 4 *dynamic* keyword when you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try LateBindingApi.Excel: http://excel.codeplex.com

Same syntax like early bind but its latebind.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Excel.Interop api. Example here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel.

Comment: Excel Interop i was using before, but that have one problem when i run my App in other Computer with a different version of the Office, he doesn't recognize the Library because have different versions.

Comment: I don't think that should matter if you copy the Excel.Interop assembly into your project output always. Include the binary with your application.